# Strange conversion operator behavior

Tags: c#

I have this struct:

```
public struct MyValue
{
    public string FirstPart { get; private set; }
    public string SecondPart { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator MyValue(string fromInput)
    { // first breakpoint here.
        var parts = fromInput.Split(new[] {'@'});
        return new MyValue(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(MyValue fromInput)
    { // second breakpoint here.
        return fromInput.ToString();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstPart + "@" + SecondPart;
    }

    public MyValue(string firstPart, string secondPart) : this()
    {
        this.FirstPart = firstPart;
        this.SecondPart = secondPart;
    }
}
```

And I've set breakpoints as indicated by the comments above.

Then I do this:

```
var first = new MyValue("first", "second");
if (first == (MyValue) null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

I'm observing some strange behavior when it enters `if (first == (MyValue) null)`: the second breakpoint is hit for some reason.  Why is it trying to convert the `MyValue` into a string for a simple equality comparison?

Then, if I let the code continue, it hits the first breakpoint, and now I'm wondering why is it trying to convert a string (the value is `null` despite the fact that I've explicitly cast `null` into a `MyValue`) into a `MyValue`?  Strings shouldn't be involved when using a statement like `if (first == (MyValue) null)`, so what is actually happening here?

Comment: which of the two implicit operators do you expect to be called when you supply `null`?

Comment: Neither, because I'm "not" converting anything.  But apparently I am.  Hence my question.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the missing overload for the `==` operator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Was busy commenting and it became clear what the issue is.*

The C# compiler cannot compile `(MyStruct) null`, but in your case it does.

This happens as you have an implicit operator from a reference type (this case `string`) where `null` is perfectly valid.

I think you can follow now why it executes the way you see :)

PS: This is a good example why 'lossy' implicit operators are discouraged in general.

Comment: Implicit conversions are teh devil.

Comment: can you elabprate more in more simple words

Comment: So it just picks the first (and in this case only) implicit conversion operator it finds that can convert a reference type?  Also, you say "The C# compiler cannot compile (MyStruct) null, but in your case it does." -- can you elaborate on why it does?

Comment: @roryap - no, it picks the conversion operator it is able to do to make the result of the conversion castable to `MyStruct`. And for `null` it is to string.

Comment: @roryap unless you declare a struct as nullable (either `MyValue?` or `Nullable<MyValue>`), it can never be null. Therefore, if you didn't have the implicit conversion to string it would throw a compiler error. Since you *do* have the implicit conversion, it says "hey, this can be a string, which *can* be nullable" so it converts it to a string and performs the equality check.

Comment: @DaveZych -- That clears it up for me.  Perfect.  That you.  That's what I was missing -- you can't ever compare a value type to null just on its own.  That's something I knew very well but which I had apparently temporarily forgotten.

Comment: @DaveZych -- And, indeed, if I comment out the implicit operators, I get a compiler error "Cannot convert null to 'ConsoleApplication3.MyValue' because it is a non-nullable value type" as expected.

Comment: leppie I've accepted your answer, but I have to say I had to read over it a bunch of times and also see @YuvalItzchakov's answer before I really understood what you are saying.  I think you could improve your answer by making it clearer, if not for me then for anyone else who comes across this question.  For instance, you say "I think you can follow now why it executes the way you see :)" but I don't think you can make that assumption.  Anyway, for your consideration...

Answer (score 7):

To complete [@leppies answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895735/1870803), this is the calling code (Release mode):

```
public void X()
{
    var first = new MyValue("first", "second");
    if (first == (MyValue) null) throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Which actually compiles to this:

```
public void X()
{
    if (new MyValue("first", "second") == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

And this is the emitted IL for the call:

```
// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void X () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x20dc
    // Code size 45 (0x2d)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldstr "first"
    IL_0005: ldstr "second"
    IL_000a: newobj instance void MyValue::.ctor(string, string)
    IL_000f: call string MyValue::op_Implicit(valuetype MyValue)
    IL_0014: ldnull
    IL_0015: call valuetype MyValue MyValue::op_Implicit(string)
    IL_001a: call string MyValue::op_Implicit(valuetype MyValue) <--- This!
    IL_001f: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
    IL_0024: brfalse.s IL_002c
    IL_0026: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.InvalidOperationException::.ctor()
    IL_002b: throw
    IL_002c: ret
} // end of method C::X
```

As you can see, after you create the new instance of `MyValue`, operation `IL_001a` calls the implicit conversion to `string`, as **that is the only possibility for the compiler to make the value type comparison to `null` actually compile.**

Comment: In C#, this is: `if ((string)new MyValue("first", "second") == (string)(MyValue)((string)null)) throw new InvalidOperationException();`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Not exactly. He's declaring an `implicit` cast to `string`, not an explicit one.

Comment: Yes, I just made everything explicit to show what's going on.